# open last activity when the app is killed

Tags: android, android-activity, kill

then in my app there are 103 activity, in sequence
SplashActivity -> Menu ---> Q_001 ---> Q_002 ... (...) ..... Q_finish.
in each of the activity I have a button to put exit from the app (like a home button), and a button that returns to the Menu.
Now I want that if the user kills the app, and open it at another time returns to the activity that was using,

I know I have to try to change the SpalshActivity The last activity you were doing, if you were not carrying out any activity to continue His Work
this is the code of SplashActivity:

```
package org.somename;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisIsAwesome) {
        super.onCreate(TravisIsAwesome);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);



        Thread logoTimer = new Thread (){


            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(500);
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent("org.somename.MENU");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();

                }
            }
    };

    logoTimer.start();


    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

keep saying that I do not care about saving activity menu, but all the activities starting from "Q_001" and ending activity "Q_finish." I tried to use new this method: I have suggested in the previous question and I have implemented this code:

```
package org.somename;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisIsAwesome) {
        super.onCreate(TravisIsAwesome);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

         int last_activity = getLastActivityIdFromSharedPreferences();
            if (last_activity == 1)
            {
                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, Q_001.class));
                finish();
            }

            int last_activity2 = getLastActivityIdFromSharedPreferences2();
            if (last_activity2 == 2)
            {
                this.startActivity(new Intent(this, Q_002.class));
                finish();
            }

        Thread logoTimer = new Thread (){


            @Override
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(500);
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent("org.somename.MENU");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();

                }
            }
    };

    logoTimer.start();


    }






    private int getLastActivityIdFromSharedPreferences2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }






    private int getLastActivityIdFromSharedPreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

but it is not part of the SplahActivity, and does not return to the Activity executed .
goes directly to the menu, with a SplahActivity of blank page

Thank in advance

Comment: 1. Splash screens are usually frowned upon in Android (read this, for example : http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)
2. 103 Activities ! Sounds like you have a design problem ! If you could explain what you app is doing exactly, we could probably help you with that ... 
3. What is that menuIntent doing exactly ?

Comment: I am developing a quiz, in the 103  activity there are 100 questions

Comment: are each quizz question really complex? Like video + drawing? or just trivial pursuit quizz?

Comment: there is a webview and 4 buttons in each Activity

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @2Dee.

First thoughts were that your are not really learning the current Android development, I think. I suppose most people would go for one activity for splash (if you really need one) and a second activity for holding the 100 buttons. This 100 buttons would be hold inside a viewpager. It is a bit more complex to understand at first but it is the way to go, in my opinion. The view pager will recycle, is efficient and a powerful tool to leverage.

But maybe you are doing  a school exercise ?

Edit: I see 2 ways, probably someone can find better.

1. You can save in memory where the user is. When the user click to exit, just save in a SharedPreferences the current question and retrieve it at start : [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)
2. You can make that clicking exit button jsut call onBackPressed() and maybe override onBackPressed. If you do that the activity will be send to background and the user to Home. If he goes back to it, it will restart on that last activity. You must still save it in case the user kill the app or Android kills the app for ressource management.

Edit 2 :

In Splash Activity, you **retrieve** an integer. in the main activity (the one holding the question and the buttons) you **write** the question number.

That gave something like that :

splash activity :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(LAST_QUESTION, 0);
   int number = settings.getInt("last_question", 1); // default value is to start again
   goToQuestionNumber(number); // you better call this in onResume(). 
}
```

In the exiting method launched by the onClik()

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(LAST_QUESTION, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("last_question", currentQuestionNumberThatYouShouldKnow);
```

Comment: no I'm not doing an academic exercise, I just wanted to open the last activity
when the app is dead

Comment: but since my start page is a splash activity I wanted some help from you who are more experienced than me

Comment: I edited. You will find enough code at the link I gave you, I hope. Ask me if you need more.

Comment: I read the sharedpreference, but I do not understand what code could help me because, in my opinion I have to implement something in splahActivity or in MenuActivity to try the last activity saved

Comment: You need no splash screen at all. You can load the question from the local memory, or one by one as the player goes forth from a server. Handset are now very powerful. You should **really** look at ViewPager. You can even just change the WebView displayed

Comment: Sorry what constant I have to put in LAST_QUESTION?

Comment: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,int)) 
Little by little, try to search more by yourself. It is a string that you define yourself :  `private String LAST_QUESTION = "lastQuestionUserDid";` It is good habit to define a constant for code maintenance.

Comment: in SplashActivity the code open this:                                    private void goToQuestionNumber(int number) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

Comment: if you want to place the code that I'm implementing to be more clear

Comment: goToQuestionNumber is a method you have to write yourself. Look carefully at @2Dee's answer, there are lot of things you need inside to get a more general view. But I think you should start to do things yourself for some hours now and try to understand. There are lot of dummies project that you should learn to download and run in order to understand what you can do and have a full app code. better than trying to get it all done on stackoverflow.com. Here is for you : https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus TRy to run some of his project (viewpager and such). Look his code. LOVE THAT MAN !!

Comment: I did not expect to be so complicated restore activity  :,(

Comment: +1 on trying to understand CommonsWare projects, it's a gold mine ! Before starting large projects I read other people's code and tried to understand it. If you have the time and motivation, read Reto Meier's Professional Android 4 Apps Development, one of the best books out there to learn about the Android SDK. You could also join forums or Google+ communities to ask for tutorials/learning resources.

Comment: It's not that restoring an Activity is hard, but your app coding design is not efficient at all, not easily maintainable, and overall cumbersome. Read about how pros like CommonsWare or Lars Vogel (http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) do it, and you will see your app could be much simpler to make ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I thought, I believe you need to rethink your app's architecture :)

Make one Activity and one Fragment. The Activity will be responsible for switching the Fragment in view and creating them. It will also hold a reference to the urls necessary for the webviews.

This is the way I would do it (but it might take a complete refactoring of your code - which is not a bad exercise if you think about it) :

in Activity :

```
// declare your urls in the res/values/strings.xml and use them here.
private int[] webViewsUrls = {R.string.url1, R.string.url2, ...};
```

in Activity's onCreate :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
int activityIndex = prefs.getInt("lastActivityIndex", 0);
QuestionFragment fragment = new QuestionFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("INDEX", activityIndex);
bundle.putString("WEBVIEW_URL", webViewsUrls[activityIndex]);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
// Show fragment
```

To add a new Fragment to a ViewGroup inside your Activity layout (if you don't use a ViewPager but rather use a button to change the question in view) :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// create you fragment using the method I give above
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_in_activity_layout, fragment, STRING_FRAGMENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

To replace the fragment already in view, use the [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) method instead of add.

The on click on a button, or in a ViewPager, change the Fragment in view and do not forget to save the new value for activityIndex in SharedPreferences when starting your Fragment.

I believe the suggestion of @Poutrathor is quite good, you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839550/how-to-set-view-pager-for-each-item-of-a-list/19840146#19840146) I gave yesterday if you want to use ViewPager, which I think would fit your requirements better than having 100+ Activities.

Comment: I am sure that I will take in cosider your help, but I think at another time, because my app is almost complete I was just looking for a way to remember the last activity which is being closed, but thank you for your help

Comment: I urge you to reconsider, think about this : if you app needs updating, you have 103 classes to modify and 103 layout files to edit. Using a ViewPager and Fragments, you have 2 classes, and 2 layout files to modify. And it will make you apk much lighter as well. Definitely a no-brainer as far as I'm concerned ;)

Comment: you know you're right, and in the manner described above ke you can reopen the last session that the user have closed?

Comment: Yes, when your activity starts, it will check if activityIndex exists, and add the corresponding Fragment to the ViewGroup that should contain it, or add the default first Fragment, that's what the 0 is for in prefs.getInt, setting index to the first element if SharedPrefs does not contain the int with key lastActivityIndex... Do not forget to save the new index in the Fragment's onStart, and let the magic happen ;) That way, you also get rid of the SplashActivity, by the way.