# Start same android last activity on relaunch after closing the app

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an app that is having function to upload images to instagram. So when i upload the image to instagram and press the home button,the app is closed and when i ma relaunching the app it is starting from the main[ splash screen] activity.

In that application i am having option to take images from gallery and the camera. So when i press the home button and relaunch the app it should start the activity where i can chose the images.

I have tried a lot. If anyone have the solution please help me out.

Comment: you can use shared Preference to save your position in app and in first activity check that

Comment: Post your code of activity, Normally it wont close, May be you are calling finish somewhere

Comment: see it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353900/shared-preferences-reset-data-when-app-is-force-closed-or-device-is-restarted

Comment: may be comment by Arju 34 is possible or your app is consuming more memory so OS is destroying the activity stack,
try  android:largeHeap=true in the manifest's application tag

Comment: This answer may help you. This is not my post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860321/open-last-activity-when-the-app-is-killed

Comment: This answer may help you. This is not my post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860321/open-last-activity-when-the-app-is-killed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default last activity will open when relaunch the app.But some device it will not happen.
I don't know the proper reason but may there is settings problem in that device.

Answer (score 0):

By default the last activity will be shown when the app is restarted. Unless you have added any 'no history flag' or:

```
 android:noHistory="true"
```

Set noHistory to false. ..